# Appending (uint8_t)0x00 to a std::string causes ambiguous overload error on cygwin?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Am I going crazy, or is this a bug with the cygwin g++ compiler?

This works:

```
std::string record;
record += (uint8_t)1;
```

It also is totally cool with appending a const variable with value 0:

```
const uint8_t tZero = 0x00;
std::string record;
record += tZero;
```

However, running this code causes an ambiguous operator overload error:

```
std::string record;    
record += (uint8_t)0;
```

The candidates it provides make no sense given the explicit cast, especially since one of the candidates seems to be identical to what is given in the error:

```
sources/logger.cpp:55:20: error: ambiguous overload for `operator+=' (operand types are `std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and `uint8_t {aka unsigned char}')
    record += (const uint8_t)0;

note: candidates:
    operator+=(const basic_string& __str)
    operator+=(const _CharT* __s)
    operator+=(_CharT __c)
```

This error also does NOT appear in visual studio, it compiles and appends a 0x00 byte just as I expect.

For reference, I'm using strings as buffers for binary log data. There's probably a better container to use, but being able to += bytes in is too useful to not have.

Does cygwin have a bug with its string implementation, or is this supposed to cause an error since it's 0? I don't mind using a const variable to fix the error, but it will look weird since this process is repeated multiple times through the code with other values.

Comment: Try to cast it to a `char`?

Comment: _"especially since one of the candidates seems to be identical to what is given in the error:"_ Which one? `char` is not identical to `unsigned char`

Comment: @kennytm It's a preference of mine to explicitly state what size my variables are (I do a lot of embedded development), which is why I hadn't cast to `char`. According to the answer, you're correct, and that would work. @Jonathan I guess I assumed that the signedness wouldn't matter in picking the matching pattern. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly recent change to the C++ language. Nowadays, your code should call `operator+=(_CharT)`. In the past, your code should fail due to an ambiguity even with `const uint8_t tZero = 0x00;`. You're dealing with a compiler that's partially implemented that change.

Before that change to the language, any integer constant expression with a value of zero was implicitly convertible to any pointer type and yielded a null pointer. That's why `(uint8_t)0` could be converted to `char`, or to `const char *`.

Now, only a literal `0` can be converted to pointer types. `tZero`, or even `(uint8_t)0`, should no longer convert to `const char *`. This resolves the ambiguity: only the conversion to `char` still remains as a possibility.

Comment: That makes sense. I was under the impression a `char` was just a typedef'd `sint8_t`, but am I now correct in saying they are handled differently?

I have a preference for always using the fixed size integer types, which is why I hadn't cast to `char` (I do a lot of Arduino development, and like to explicitly state what size my types are).

Comment: @DweebsUnited Since `sint8_t` and `uint8_t` are distinct types, on systems where `char` and `sint8_t` are the same type, `char` and `uint8_t` would necessarily be different types.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It seems I put too much trust in letting the compiler deduce what I wanted to do. I'm also starting to realize strings really weren't designed to do what I'm doing with them.